# Controlling Group order in a Kendo UI Grid

Tags: c#, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there a way to control the order of the grouping in a Kendo UI grid. There is a group I would like to go before all other groups, but it seems Kendo UI grid sorts the groups alphabetically. I know that adding a space to the grouping name works but that's seems very hackish.

Thanks
Leo

Comment: Thanks for the tip about adding a space in front of the name (from the back end) - the space is actually removed when it gets rendered in the UI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is currently no way to sort a grouping on something other than the group's field. Having a way to sort groups like Telerik does in their non-Kendo grids is my biggest feature request for them right now. So we are stuck using hacks for now.

One hack that works for me is to combine the sorting field and the display field into a new string column that hides the sorting field portion inside a hidden span. This is done on the data source side (for me, in SQL). The new column is then sorted as a string even if the sorting field was a number, so you have to pad appropriately in some cases.

For example, if my data was:

```
[ 
    { 
      'Name': 'Alice', 
      'Rank': 10, 
      'RankName': '<span class="myHiddenClass">10</span>Alice', 
      ... (other fields)
    },  
    { 
      'Name': 'Bob', 
      'Rank': 9, 
      'RankName': '<span class="myHiddenClass">09</span>Bob', 
      ... (other fields)
    },  
    { 
      'Name': 'Eve', 
      'Rank': 11, 
      'RankName': '<span class="myHiddenClass">11</span>Eve', 
      ... (other fields)
    } 
    ... (Multiple Alice / Bob / Eve records)
]
```

Then I can group by the RankName field instead of the Name field. It will display the Name field in the group header but be sorted by the Rank field. In this case, Bob will show up as the first group even though Alice was first alphabetically. This works similarly to the space padding you mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

Try **AddDescending** and **AddAscending**, see examples below

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<T>()
[... other code ...]
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Read(read => read.Action("action", "controller"))
    .Group(g => g.AddDescending(model=> model.property)) // <-- subtle difference here!
)
[... other code ...]
)
```

http://www.telerik.com/forums/stacked-chart-legend-order

Comment: I was able to apply the sort order to Kendo Grid. **AddDescending** and **AddAscending** works fine without any issues

Answer (score 3):

Kendo's grouping sorts all elements in the array by a given field (for example `fooBar`), then iterates the sorted elements. In a nutshell, with pseudo code:

```
if (element[i].fooBar!= element[i-1].fooBar) { 
    StartNewGroup(element[i]);
} else {
    AddToLastGroup(element[i]);
}
```

Since the sorted array is required to do the grouping, it is tricky to change the sorting. I created code to override the internal `groupBy()` function, which allows me to sort the grouped results however I like:

```
function overrideKendoGroupBy() {
    var origFunc = kendo.data.Query.prototype.groupBy;
    kendo.data.Query.prototype.groupBy = function (descriptor) {
        var q = origFunc.call(this, descriptor);

        var data = SortYourData(q.data, descriptor.dir);

        return new kendo.data.Query(data);
    };
}
```

Call `overrideKendoGroupBy()` at some point after your page loads. Now just implement a `SortYourData()` function where `q.data` is an array of groupings, and `descriptor.dir` is `"asc"` or `"desc"`. `q.data[n]` has an `items` array that contains the elements from your original data source that are contained in the `n`th grouping.

Note: This solution only works if you aren't using paging. The pages are broken up before grouping is applied, so all bets are off if your data spans multiple pages.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will push the group that fulfils the `if` condition to bottom of the grid

```
group: {
    dir: "asc",
    field: "FieldToGroupBy",
    compare: function (a, b) {
        if (b.value == "GROUP_TO_SHOW_LAST") {
            return -1; // this will push the group to bottom
        }
    }
},
```

If you want to compare groups with each other, you should use `a` and `b` and then set the *return value* accordingly.
You need to play around with the *return value* based on your requirement.

Note: return value should be any of 0, 1, -1

Answer (score 0):

Custom sorting direction when grouping is **not** supported by the Grid - the groups are sorted the same way as the column is sorted (when using client sorting) when there is not grouping. The sorting direction is the same as the default sort in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a query after you have defined the datasource and this seems to work

```
 related.query({
        sort: { field: "Sort", dir: "asc"},
        group: { field: "CategoryName" },
        pageSize: 50
    });
```

Where related is the name of the datasource

Answer (score 0):

An old question but I just had the same issue

In theory you can follow the advice here: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/4024

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...
    groupable: {
        sort: {
            dir: "asc",
            compare: function compareByTotal(a, b) {
                if (a.items.length === b.items.length) {
                    return 0;
                } else if (a.items.length > b.items.length) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However this didn't work for me.

What did work for me was...

Add an extra column to your dataSource, so now you have

- GroupByName
- GroupByOrder

In your schema do

```
dataSource = {
                data: dataProperties,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            groupByName: {
                                type: "string",
                                from: "dataPropertyDefinition.GroupName"
                            },
                            groupOrderBy: {
                                type: "string",
                                from: "dataPropertyDefinition.groupOrderBy"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                group: {
                    field: "groupOrderBy",
                }
            };
```

So now you are ordering by groupOrderBy, which can be whatever you like, and you use the groupHeaderTemplate to show the name instead

```
        const columns: Array<object> = [
            {
                field: "groupOrderBy",
                hidden: true,
                groupHeaderTemplate: function (x: any)
                {
                    return x.items[0].groupByName;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple workaround for this. Not pretty but simple enough...

**Just add spaces in front of the text to achieve desirable sorting**

```
   [{ 
      'Value': 1, 
      'Description': 'Description 1', 
      'Grouping': 'Group 1'
    },  
    { 
      'Value': 2, 
      'Description': 'Description 2', 
      'Grouping': ' Group 2'
    },
    { 
      'Value': 3, 
      'Description': 'Description 3', 
      'Grouping': 'Group 3'
    }]
```

In the sample code above ***Group 2*** appears before ***Group 1***  because of a leading space.

Answer (score -2):

Use columns to specify the order of columns once you have your data such as

```
columns: [
{
field: "LastName",
title: "Last Name" 
},
{
field: "FirstName",
title: "First Name"
}
]
```