# Kendo Grid custom grouping sort order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out how to have a custom sorting for a column when grouped. Here is a screenshot depicting how I'd like this to work:

[image]

In the screenshot, I am defaulting the grouping by the "**Status**" column. The column has four possible values: **Unsafe | Quarantined | Waived | Abnormal**. The normal sorting goes by an alphabetical sorting, but I am looking to have just the grouping sorting of the "**Status**" column sort by **Unsafe | Quarantined | Waived | Abnormal**. Is this possible to just have the grouping sorting of the column "Status" in the order I described?

If this is not possible, what are my options? Thanks!

Comment: Not directly supported but this post has a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366450/controlling-group-order-in-a-kendo-ui-grid

Comment: Sounds like a capable workaround. We could use an enum for the Status column and convert it via a ClientTemplate. That would just mean we have to create a custom filter function for this column too...

Comment: I added a new answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366450/controlling-group-order-in-a-kendo-ui-grid, which is probably also relevant here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How I ended up achieving this was creating an enum for this property, which was sorted in the custom order I wanted. Then, I just used `.ClientTemplate()` and `.ClientGroupHeaderTemplate()` to convert these values into the correct strings.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by returning a calculated field with your data that is a numeric value representing the items order in the sort. Then group by the calculated field but display the status value in the group header.

I used a hack to get this to work and it basically goes like this:

In the Controller:

```
foreach (MyCustomModelitem in MyCustomModel)
{
    item.CustomGroupField= item.Status+ "_@@" + MyGetSortIndexForStatus(item.Status).ToString();
}
```

In the View

```
.Columns(columns =>
{   
    columns.Bound(t => t.CustomGroupField).Width(185).Title("Status")
      .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("# var a = value.split('_@@')  # #=a[0]#")   
      .ClientTemplate("${Status}")
      .Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("customFieldFilter"));      
})
....
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(750)  
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetSummaryData", "MyContgroller", @Model))
    .ServerOperation(true)           
    .Group(grp =>
     {
         if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@Model.Groups))
             foreach(string g in @Model.Groups.Split(','))           
                 grp.Add(g, typeof(string));
     })
 )
```

Optional Custom Drop Down List

```
function customFieldFilter(element) {
    if (element == null) return;
    element.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Status",
        dataValueField: "CustomSortField",                
        dataSource: {
            transport: {                       
                read: "@Url.Action("GetMyStatuses", "MyController")"
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sounds like a similar solution we came up with too. I'll check it out and let you know how it goes.