# How to change the order of a group using Kendo grid?

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid

Mates, I would like to modify the group order, I did many searchs and nothing was found besides ASC and DES order. I've that sequence defined by kendo(Alfabetic order):

https://dojo.telerik.com/AJomALET/6

Sequence that I want:

Boston Crab Meat,
Camembert Pierrot,
Chang,
Aniseed Syrup,
....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you export your `kendo` grid in PDF, it will copy the grid's style and data ,on how your grid is shown in the page. The best thing you can do is to make a custom sorting/ranking of your `kendo` grid groups before exporting. See this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366450/controlling-group-order-in-a-kendo-ui-grid)**.

Comment: In the newest version released they have done a feature that solve this problem.